# How to get selected value of dropdown list in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am stuck in this code unable to retain the value of `dropdown` on submitting.

```
$uCars=array("BMW","Honda","XUV","Safari","Mercedes","Volvo");
.....
if ($_POST['uCars'])
    $uSelectCar = $_POST['uCars'];  
    ....
    <select name="uCar">
    <?php
            foreach($uCars as $uCar) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $uCar?>"     name="uCars[]" <?php echo if($uCar=$uSelectCar) echo "selected='selected'?> ><?php echo $uCar ?></option>
    <?php
    } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: What is the name of your select?

Comment: Use double equal signs for comparisons.

Comment: The value will be in `$_POST['uCars']` as you have it. You probably want something like `if (!empty($_POST['uCars'])) { /* do something  */ }`. Doing `if ($_POST['uCars'])` is a bad idea because if the value is not set PHP will produce a notice and if the value is equal to `0` it will evaluate to `false` and will not trigger the code after it.

Comment: `echo if($uCar=$uSelectCar)` that will fail for 2 reasons. Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and you'll see.

Comment: Also get rid of the `name` attribute on the `<option>` tags. It goes on `<select>` only.

Comment: Good eye/call @Mike so many syntax errors here, I could stitch a 4x8 canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your option value builder is wrong, you have several syntax errors, you have an unclosed quote after the if statement, your if statement is not encapsulated, you have an echo before the if statement and your comparison is not correct it should consist of 2 equal signs to signify both should be the "same":

```
<?php echo if($uCar=$uSelectCar) echo "selected='selected'?>
```

Which should actually be

```
<?php if($uCar == $uSelectCar) { echo "selected='selected'" } ?>
```

The completed code is below

```
<select name="uCars">
    <?php
            foreach($uCars as $uCar) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $uCar; ?>" <?php if($uCar == $uSelectCar) { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>><?php echo $uCar; ?></option>
    <?php
            } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: *"you have several syntax errors"* - which are?

Comment: For example an unclosed echo inside the if statement and an echo before the if statement.

Comment: personally, I outline their errors in an answer, rather than in comments and just dropping code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel !! Its working now..